# Ошибка с delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Обновил Xcode 6.3.1 и вылезла ошибка, где ее не было:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id < UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, HPTextViewTapGestureRecognizerDelegate > delegate;
```

Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'delegate'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention

У кого есть решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это значит, что уже есть @property с таким именем и нужно выбрать другое имя. Оно может быть уже задано у родительского класса.

Comment: спасибо--так и оказалось!